# $f_1,...,f_n$ be linear functionals on a real vector space $V$, then is there a norm on $V$ which makes every $f_i$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a real vector space, $f_1,...,f_n$ be linear functionals on $V$; then does there exist a norm on $V$ with respect to which each of $f_i$ is continuous? And what if we have infinitely many, linearly independent, such functionals?

Comment: Just in general, don't add spaces between the end of a word and punctuation. For example, it should be "...such functionals?" and not "...such functionals ?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for infinitely many functionals is no; there's a counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749864/can-the-real-vector-space-of-all-real-sequences-be-normed-so-that-it-is-complete/1749895?noredirect=1#comment3571929_1749895).

For finitely many functionals it must be yes...

Right. First, there is a norm on any real vector space $X$, for example if $B$ is a (Hamel) basis define $$\left\vert\left\vert\sum_{b\in B}c_b b\right\vert\right\vert=\sum_{b\in B}|c_b|.$$Now if $||\cdot||$ is a norm on $X$ define a new norm by $$|||x|||=||x||+\sum_{j=1}^n|f_j(x)|.$$