# A question about Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Can we find a norm that makes the space of all real sequences a Banach space?

Comment: I think not, since this space would contain the space $\ell^{p}$ for $p<1$ which I believe is known to be only metrisable.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749864/can-the-real-vector-space-of-all-real-sequences-be-normed-so-that-it-is-complete).